# How do you use a partial in a layout template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I have a partial that I'd like to use in a layout but when I load up a page it'll look in a different folder for the partial.

So for my layout I've got.

```
%html
  %head
%body
  .content
    = yield
  .footer
  = render :partial => 'tracking'
```

And in my layouts folder I have the partial file "app/views/layouts/_tracking.html.haml" that I'd like to use in the layout for all pages. But when I load up a page It'll give me an error saying it can't find the template "products/_tracking.erb"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just use

```
= render :partial => '/layouts/tracking'
```

Comment: Don't even need the forward slash these days.

Answer (score 6):

I think you just pass it a full path to it, like

```
<%= render "shared/menu" %>
```

ref: 3.4.1 second example here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials